# Do the puzzles in observatories and manufacturing facilities reset if you get them wrong?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In my first observatory I didn't notice the number sequence in the bottom left when I was attempting to solve the puzzle, and so got the answer wrong, and then couldn't attempt it again.

Do the puzzles reset after a while allowing me to retry (possibly more important for Manufacturing Facilities where your knowledge of the language is the clue)?

Comment: I believe they will reset if you leave the system and come back. But will not until then.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but if you hit the save point right before you attempt the puzzle, you can just reload if you get it wrong. Even if it does reset,  it's probably easier to find a new building than go back to one you messed up earlier.

Comment: Cheers @Kat, I'll bear that in mind if my language skills aren't enough. I think the number one I'd find quite a way from my ship so would have lost quite a bit of progress ;)

Comment: Usually there's a save point outside  buildings, so you can save even without the ship. You can also back out of the puzzle by pressing circle (not sure what it is on PC) if you want to go save before answering. So long as you don't pick an answer, the question will still be there.

Comment: I posted them as an answer, though they still don't address the actual question.

Comment: Cheers. The answer seems to be no, so your advice will do me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Instead of trying to find your way back to a puzzle you messed up, save before answering the question, and reload if you get it wrong.**

It is much easier to reload a save than it is to find a building again. Personally, I don't think I could find a specific building I'd been to before if my life depended on it! There are save points outside of every building, so you can always easily save before trying a puzzle. You can also hop in and out of your ship quickly if it is nearby.

If you find that you are looking at a puzzle that you are unsure of the answer to, and you didn't save before starting it, **back out of the puzzle by pressing circle** instead of guessing. (I'm not sure what the key is for PC, but I'm sure it's whatever you use to exit out of other menus.) This will leave the puzzle unchanged, and you can go save and come back to it. This is also useful if you need to grab materials from your ship to select the correct option.

If you do answer a puzzle incorrectly without saving first, just let it go. Rewards are random, so you are just as likely to find the same reward at the next puzzle you come across. It's much easier to find a new building than it is to find your way back to a specific building that you messed up before. The game has more planets than you will ever have time to visit. Why waste time trying to find a specific building you failed when you can move on to something new much more easily?

Comment: When in doubt, save scum ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "It is much easier to reload a save than it is to find a building again" Most planets, at least those not covered with water, are _littered_ with buildings. You can barely fly 20 feet without finding another one. Granted it might be simpler to kind of scam the game, but...

Comment: I mean it's easier to reload than to leave and come back to that *particular* building later. You could definitely argue that it's even easier to find a new building entirely.

Answer (score 3):

They do not restore even if you go to a different solar system, the only way to redo the puzzle is to save your game before you do the puzzle and then reload your game if get the puzzle wrong. Other than that, there is no other way of being able to redo a puzzle whether you get the correct or wrong answer.